# Collatz Conjecture: If a non-trivial cycle exists, would it follow that $2^{K+L} - 3^K < (10^{-5})3^K$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, logarithms, collatz-conjecture

Does it follow from Lemma 8 in the [paper](https://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35%5DSidW-3n+1-ActaArith%5B2005%5D.pdf) by Simons and de Weger (2005) that if a non-trivial cycle exists:
$$2^{K+L} - 3^K < (10^{-5})3^K$$

Let:

- $x\ge 1$ be an integer
- $T(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2}(3x + 1), && \text{if }x\text{ is odd}\\
  \frac{1}{2}x, && \text{if }x\text{ is even}\\
  \end{cases}$
- $T_1(x) = T(x)$
- $T_{c+1}(x) = T(T_c(x))$
- $\delta = \dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2}$
- A non-trivial cycle is any case where $x > 2$ and there exists integer $c > 0$ where $T_c(x) = x$
- $[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{c-1}]$ be the distinct numbers which make up a non-trivial cycle with:

  - $K = $ the number of odd integers
  - $L = $ the number of even integers
  - $K+L = c-1$

Here's my thinking:

(1)  From Lemma 8 on page 9:

$$K + L < 1.000001\delta K$$

(2)  $2^{K+L} - 3^K < 2^{1.000001\delta K} - 2^{\delta K} = 2^{\delta K}\left(2^{.000001\delta K}  - 1\right) < 3^K(3^{.000001K} - 1) < 3^K(1.00001 - 1) = (10^{-5})3^K$

Am I understanding the implications of the lemma correctly?  Did I make a mistake?

---

**Update**:  The last part is wrong.  For larger $K$, it is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this instead: If a non-trivial m-cycle exists,

$$K+L-K\log_23<\frac{m}{X_0\log2}$$
The current $X_0=2,95...10^{20}$, so
$$(K+L)\log2-K\log3<\frac{m}{2,95\cdot 10^{20}}$$
$$\log \frac{2^{K+L}}{3^K}<\frac{m}{2,95\cdot 10^{20}}$$
$$\frac{2^{K+L}}{3^K}-1<e^\frac{m}{2,95\cdot 10^{20}}-1$$
or
$$2^{K+L}-3^K<3^K(e^\frac{m}{2,95\cdot 10^{20}}-1)$$